# Recommended textual representation for playing cards?

Tags: discussion

I am working on creating a [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) that involves using playing cards, but I am not sure what the best way to represent them textually is.

Here are some alternatives I have considered:

Note, the samples show a hand consisting of the Ace of Clubs, Ten of Clubs, Five of Hearts, Five of Spades, and Queen of Spades.

- Represent rank with digits `1`-`9` and `10`, and then `J`, `Q`, and `K`, and suit with `S` (spades), `C` (clubs), `D` (diamonds), and `H` (hearts):

  ```
  1C 10C 5H 5S QS
  ```
- Use `0` to represent a ten:

  ```
  1C 0C 5H 5S QS
  ```

  - Each card is represented by the same number of characters.
  - Somewhat less readable.
- Use numbers to represent all ranks:

  ```
  1C 10C 5H 5S 12S
  ```

  - Might be easier to parse, somehow.
- Use `♠`. `♣`, `♦`, and `♥` to represent suit:

  ```
  1♣ 10♣ 5♥ 5♠ Q♠
  ```

  - Much easier to read.
  - Might be more difficult for languages that have problems with extended charsets.
- Use `A` instead of `1`, for an ace:

  ```
  A♣ 10♣ 5♥ 5♠ Q♠
  ```

  - Makes it a little bit prettier.
- Some combination of these alternatives.
- Use a custom character set to encode the cards.

  - Much more efficient.
  - Can't view it very easily.

I am rather partial to formatting them like `A♣ 10♣ 5♥ 5♠ Q♠`, but I would like to see what others think about this issue.

Comment: I like bullet #2

Comment: I'd go for the standard representation

Comment: "T" for ten is not uncommon and it preserves a one-character rank indication which "10" does not. But for some classes of challenges maybe you don't want to make the input that much easier...

Comment: That said, I don't think we need or even should have a standard representation for absolutely everything. The author of each challenge may have a reason for choosing a particular system and who are we to gainsay that?

Answer (score 8):

[KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Sticking to ASCII makes it simpler: the byte representations will be the same in ISO-8859-1, UTF-8, and MacRoman, so people don't have to worry about ensuring that they're using the correct character encoding. (Of course, they *should* as a matter of principle, but this site isn't really about best practices).

Of the various ASCII options, the one I'm more familiar with from my bridge-playing days is `A23456789TJQK` `CDHS`, but the simplest for inter-program communication is probably to number the cards from `0` to `51`.

However, there's nothing which requires you to use the same format for inter-program communication and for presentation to the user. Although I recommend using ASCII for the [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) communication, the scoring program could be made more polished by using `A23456789TJQK` `♠♡♢♣` in its logs.

Answer (score -1):

Might I suggest Unicode (6+)?

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_cards_in_Unicode

**edit** This is a screenshot from Chromium on Ubuntu 14.04 of what it should look like.

[image]

Comment: In a lot of fonts these are either unsupported or really hard to distinguish unless you use a large font size.

Comment: I see boxes because I don't have the appropriate font package

Comment: On what platform are you?

Comment: The text and the image look identical to me (FF on Ubuntu), and I haven't done any fancy font stuff, so these must be supported by default on at least some systems. That said, I don't think these would be the best idea because of lack of support, at least on some platforms.

Comment: Renders OK for me on Ubuntu 14.04, but not on OSX 10.9.3.  I'm downvoting this because I don't think its worth going to all this trouble, only to have hearts and diamonds be coloured black.

Comment: I'm using [Scientific Linux 6.4](http://www.scientificlinux.org/). I don't have many Unicode fonts installed because I really don't need them & the extra fonts are really just bloat-ware, IMO.

Comment: Aside: I'm really impressed that Unicode has glyphs for the "Cavalier" cards in bizarre tarot decks.

Comment: Chrome, Windows 7: squares. Seems only Linux supports these glyphs as of now.